# Fluent NHibernate Querying: OrderBy column of joined table

Tags: c#, pagination, fluent-nhibernate, sql-order-by, queryover

I've been struggling quite some time now with trying to query some stuff using NHibernate.
I've managed to do some very simple queries, but now I'm trying to build some custom pagination through NHibernate.

What I want to do is twofold.
**First (1)** off, I want to be able to order my resultset based on a **column from a joined table**.
Let's say I have a 'Person' table that has a one-to-one (actually many-to-one) reference with an 'Address' table.
I want to query over the 'Person' table (using its fields), but want to sort using fields from the 'Address' table.

How do I do this? I've tried the following two ways

```
var resultset = GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<Person>()
                   .Where(x => x.Name == "...")
                   .JoinQueryOver<Address>(x => x.Address)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.HouseNumber).Desc
                   .Skip(...)
                   .Take(...)
                   .List();
// ==> could not execute query

Person person = null;
Address address = null;
var resultset = GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<Person>()
                   .JoinAlias(() => person, () => address.Persons)
                   .Where(() => person.Name == "...")
                   .OrderBy(() => address.HouseNumber).Asc
                   .Skip(...)
                   .Take(...)
                   .List();
// ==> could not resolve property: person of: Person
```

My **second (2)** question is, I would like to split the ordering up.
Based on conditional statements, I want to add a different OrderBy.
Can I just do it like so?

```
var query = GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<Person>()
               .Where(x => x.Name == "...")
               .JoinQueryOver<Address>(x => x.Address);

if(foo)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(() => address.HouseNumber).Asc
}
else if (bar)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(() => address.Street).Desc
}

var resultset = query                    
                   .Skip(...)
                   .Take(...)
                   .List();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give some details about the first exception ("could not execute query")? Other than that, thanks for posting a well-written question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your examples *should* work, with the small caveat that you need to assign your aliases properly in order to use them (the message *could not resolve property: person of: Person* indicates that `person` was never actually set as the alias). For example:

```
Person person = null;
Address address = null;

// Assign the person alias using () => person
var resultset = GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<Person>(() => person)
    .JoinAlias(() => person.Address, () => address) // Assign the address alias here
    .Where(() => person.Name == "...")
    .OrderBy(() => address.HouseNumber).Asc
    .Skip(...)
    .Take(...)
    .List();
```

This should work fine.

As for your second question, what you're trying to achieve is very possible, an in fact a great reason to use QueryOver to begin with. You just need a few tweaks:

```
var query = GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<Person>()
               .Where(x => x.Name == "...")
               .JoinQueryOver<Address>(x => x.Address, () => address); // assign address alias

if(foo)
{
    query.OrderBy(() => address.HouseNumber).Asc(); // <-- use the *method* .Asc()
}
else if (bar)
{
    query.OrderBy(() => address.Street).Desc(); // <-- use the *method* .Desc()
}
```

Note that since `.Asc()` and `.Desc()` actually modify the query, you don't need to reassign the query. Be sure to use the *methods* `.Asc()` and `.Desc()` so that you don't get a build error.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker Suppose we have .Skip(2)
    .Take(1),and suppose that Person have 2 addresses , why In my result only 1 address is taken? Thanks.

Comment: @MDDDC: Image the SQL that's being generated. You're joining on `Address` and then telling the database engine to only take the *first* row. That means you're only going to get the first person + address row retrieved. If you want to get a person and all of their addresses, it's best to run two queries (one to get the person and another to get all of their addresses), or get the person and let NHibernate lazy load the addresses.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker Well , I know that, but to be honest , I can't find an place where I can use this functionality.Do you know better why to implement Pagination using FLuent Nhibernate?

Comment: @MDDDC: The way I've done it in the past with *-to-many relationships like that is to do the first option I mentioned -- pull back the parent entities and then run another query for the child entities

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker , I did the same. But why there is no better way to do this? I can't imagine why there is still no other methods.
Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is dynamic sorting

```
string orderColumn = "";
            bool isAsc = (param.sSortDir_0 == "asc");
            switch (param.iSortCol_0)
            {
                case 1: orderColumn = "Approved"; break;
                case 2: orderColumn = "CreateDate"; break;
                case 3: orderColumn = "Rate"; break;
            }

            result.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new NHibernate.Criterion.Order(orderColumn, isAsc));
```